# exponential distribution cups breaking

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

let $X$ r.v. denote the time needed for the event of a cup breaking with **exp$(\frac{1}{24})$** distribution, in other words a cup breaks every 24 months(expected value).

If I want to know what is the probability of **at most** $k$ cups breaking out of $n$ total cups in a **year**, how would I formulate that?

What I understand is this:

**P$(X\leq12)$**=$1-(1-e^{-\frac{12}{24}})=e^{-0.5}\approx 0.606$

is the probability that one cup breaks in a year, I am having problem understanding how do I define an inequality for less than equal 3 cups and same time restrict the rate of the exponential function to 12 months.

Is it just:

$1$ cup $=$ $24$ months  $\rightarrow   $3cups$ =72$ month

so, our new rate is $\lambda = \frac{1}{72}$

then, answer would be:  **P**$(Y<12)$, where $Y$ stands for 3 cups breaking, but then that would only consider 3 cups breaking not at most 3.

Or is it by reducing the rate into : $\frac{1}{12}$ and somehow changing our axis into cups instead of time?

Any help is appreciated as I got really confused here with the exponential dist.

Comment: You can add $P(\text{exactly $1$ cup breaks}) + P(\text{exactly $2$ cups break}) + P(\text{exactly $3$ cups break})$ to get the probability that at most $3$ cups break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the breaking or otherwise of each individual cup occurs independently of any of the others, the number out of $\ n\ $ cups that break in a year will be binomially distributed with parameters $\ n\ $ and $\ p=e^{-0.5}\ $:
$$
P(\text{exactly }j \text{ cups break})={n\choose k}e^{-0.5 j}\left(1-e^{-0.5}\right)^{n-j}\ .
$$
Therefore
$$
P(\text{at most }k \text{ cups break})=\sum_{j=0}^k{n\choose k}e^{-0.5 j}\left(1-e^{-0.5}\right)^{n-j}\ .
$$